# New Graphics Card - Works Once Windows 10 Fully Loaded

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I have a Lenovo E50-00 in which I've recently installed an Asus Radeon HD 5450.

When I switch on the computer, it begins to load as usual. However, there is no output onto the screen (namely I cannot see the BIOS startup and the windows loading spinner).

However once Windows 10 actually starts then the outputs on the monitors appear.

Does anyone have any idea why this is?

Thanks.

Comment: It could be using the external port before it boots, then switches to built in display.

Comment: What model of monitor do you have?  Which video connector do you use?

Comment: I'm using the DVI port for a Dell PB1914S and the HDMI on an AOC - model can't remember however purchased a few months ago.

Comment: @mt025 I've disabled the external port - assuming by that mean the motherboard built in VGA?

Comment: Why the down vote? Still don't have a concrete answer/solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your computer has onboard video and the BIOS is too dumb to realize that nothing is connected to those outputs.  Of course, when Windows boots and loads the video driver, your card becomes the default output device and you see everything normally.

You can go into your BIOS to see if there is a setting for this (of course, you'd have to plug your screen into an onboard output first).  Many have the option to disable the onboard video or select an add-on card as the primary video device.

If the BIOS does not have any settings to control this feature, your only choice is to use one of your monitor's alternate inputs (most have two or more) to connect to the motherboard and use the input button on your screen to switch to it when you need to.  That way, you're not unplugging/replugging cords every time you have to go into your BIOS.

Comment: HI, But I've already disabled the onboard video and selected the the add-on card as the primary video device